# How to test (in google test) that a function is called with the correct parameters

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a class and this class has a method ("original_method") that uses two objects of different types. In this method there are two calls: one call to a method of the first object that returns a value which is then used for calling a method of the second object. I was wondering what is the correct way of unit testing such behavior (using google-test). Specifically, I want to test that the argument provided to the second object is indeed the value returned from the first.

Currently I achieve this using parametrized tests - the code below shows what I do:

```cpp
TEST_P(SomeTestSuite, checkingIfCalledWithTheRightArgument)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*obj1, get_some_value()).WillOnce(Return(name_of_value));
    EXPECT_CALL(*obj2, do_a_calculation(name_of_value));

    obj0->call_original_method();
}
```

I have a fixture for my original class under testing, i have mocks for obj1 and obj2, I provide a value for "name_of_value" in the parameters and the test works.

My problem is that this doesn't seem to be the correct way, I believe I shouldn't have to pass a parameter to check such a functionality. I would appreciate if somebody could explain to me how i should have approached the problem.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I think I could do:

```cpp
TEST_F(SomeTestSuite, checkingIfCalledWithTheRightArgument)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*obj1, get_some_value());

    auto name_of_value = obj1->get_some_value();

    EXPECT_CALL(*obj2, do_a_calculation(name_of_value));

    obj0->call_original_method();
}
```

but I'm not sure if this captures (or actually tests) the original behaviour...

Comment: Are you testing the internal details/implementation of the function? Or is it part of the function specification that the second function will be called with the result of the first function?

Comment: Why do you think this is an incorrect approach? You have a unit under test (UUT), which has two mocked dependencies to other classes. The logic of UUT is that result of call to one dependency is then used for call to second dependency and that is tested. Everything seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @TrickorTreat if i understand the question correctly,  I only check functionality (part of the function specification): I check that when calling "original_method", two calls happen and the second one takes as a parameter the return value of the first. I don't check (at this test or in a later test) eg that  some return value is correct etc.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I think it's incorrect due to the use of parameters: in the same file I have "INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P" that provides a value for the parameter "name_of_value" - it feels redundant  since I don't care about the actual value but just that that value will be used later.